# How to submit list of files(to be uploaded) in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working on a commenting part of a website. Here, For one particular comment, user can attach several files and when the form is submitted(I am using the `@Html.BeginForm`), the list of `HttpPostedFileBase` should be submitted then inside the method the uploading has to be done. I am kind of lost in this scenario. What should be the proper way of doing this?

PS: These files are small in size.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple as that, If there are more than one files to be uploaded. For example if there are two inputs, where type is "file" that can be passed.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Method", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
   <input type='file' name='filename' id='fileid' />
   <input type='file' name='filename' id='fileid' />

}
```

This can be easily cough in the post method as

```
public ActionResult Upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> filename)
{
    //uploading to the server is done here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example

```
public string Upload(image image, HttpPostedFileBase filedata)
        {

              var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filedata.FileName);
              var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/"), fileName);
              var extension = Path.GetExtension(path);
              filedata.SaveAs(path);

              if (ModelState.IsValid)
              {

                      image.image_name = fileName;
                      image.image_description = extension;


                      db.image.AddObject(image);
                      db.SaveChanges();
                  }



              }
            return "ok";
        }
```

Comment: My issue is not with the utility, It is with the passing a list of `HttpPostedFileBase`. What I have found so far is, we can get a `IEnumerable` list of `HttpPostedFileBase`. My current problem is to collect this list of `HttpPostedFileBase` in the View.